# Monaco editor highlighted text (selected-text) positioning off

Tags: monaco-editor

I have added a monaco editor to a test screen in my local app, but when I select text the selected text highlight all seems to be raised incorrectly(?).

I am using the following sources:

```
<script type="text/Javascript" src="https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>

<link href="https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As seen in a tiny jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/eajgr2y9/10/

but when I run it within my larger environment locally I get something like the image here.....[image]

I have tried playing with `.monaco-editor .selected-text`  and `.monaco-editor .view-line` but these don't seem to improve things.

I have a very large number of CSS selectors already - but can't see what would be affecting the editor selected-text

Additionally - I've noticed that regardless of where I click on the editor content - the cursor is painted on the first line (although typing from the click position seems to proceed where you would expect)

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: That looks very much like the selection layer is misplaced. Check out the CSS applied to it.

Comment: Any suggestion which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had a `line-height` override on `div`, so I've fixed it using the following:

```
.monaco-editor * div {
    line-height:unset;
}
```